# Carregar JST Manual

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Eu tenho uma aplicação em MVC que funciona perfeitamente, onde utiliza-se JST, e ele carrega tudo certinho, desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém agora estou adicionando esta parte em angular, e não consigo carregar os templates, eu pensei em carregar eles manuais, porém nem sei se é possível.

Aqui é o meu HTML do componente

```
 <div id="gantEditorTemplates" style="display:none;">
    <div class="__template__" type="GANTBUTTONS">
    </div>
    <div class="__template__" type="TASKSEDITHEAD">
    </div>
    <div class="__template__" type="TASKROW">
    </div>
    <div class="__template__" type="TASKEMPTYROW">
    </div>
    <div class="__template__" type="TASKBAR">
    </div>
    <div class="__template__" type="CHANGE_STATUS">
    </div>
    <div class="__template__" type="TASK_EDITOR">
    </div>
    <div class="__template__" type="ASSIGNMENT_ROW">
    </div>
    <div class="__template__" type="RESOURCE_EDITOR">
    </div>
    <div class="__template__" type="RESOURCE_ROW">
    </div>

</div>
```

Aqui é como eu inicializo os templates.

```
    $.JST = {
  _templates: new Object(),
  _decorators:new Object(),
```

Aqui é o arquivo JQuery que pega os templates, porém por ser uma aplicação em angular, não sei como fazer, por isso pensei em carregá-los manualmente.
É possível fazer isso? Existe alguma outra forma de se fazer ?
Já pesquisei muito na internet, porém não achei nenhuma informação que pudesse me ajudar.